# How to fetch Object inside Array of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping

How to fetch Object inside Array of Array? I am getting undefined

```
myArray = [
  [{ name: test1, username: sampleuser1 }],
  [{ name: test2, username: sampleuser2 }],
  [{ name: test3, username: sampleuser3 }]
  
  ];


const forEachUser = await Promise.all(myArray[[0]].map(async (userSelected) => 
        {
            engagements.push(buildEmailPayload(bridgeInfo, userSelected, incident));
            const callPayload = buildCallPayload(bridgeInfo, userSelected, incident);
            
        })
```

this is my code
I'm trying to run the function in each of the username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get those user object by two methods:

```
let myArray = [
   [{ name: "test1", username: "sampleuser1" }],
   [{ name: "test2", username: "sampleuser2" }],
   [{ name: "test3", username: "sampleuser3" }]
];
```

1.Using index value

```
const forEachUser = await Promise.all(
myArray.map(userSelected => {
    engagements.push(buildEmailPayload(bridgeInfo, userSelected[0], incident));
    return buildCallPayload(bridgeInfo, userSelected[0], incident);
 })
);
```

2.Using `Array.flat` method, this makes one level array

```
const forEachUser = await Promise.all(
myArray[[0]].flat().map(userSelected => {
    engagements.push(buildEmailPayload(bridgeInfo, userSelected, incident));
    const callPayload = buildCallPayload(bridgeInfo, userSelected, incident);
    return callPayload
 })
);
```

> `Promise.all` needs array of promises you need to return some promise

Answer (score 0):

To fetch an object inside an array of arrays, you can use the index of the outer array and the index of the inner array to access the desired object. In the provided code, `myArray` is an array of arrays, where each inner array contains an object with `name` and `username`

```
myArray = [
  [{ name: 'test1', username: 'sampleuser1' }],
  [{ name: 'test2', username: 'sampleuser2' }],
  [{ name: 'test3', username: 'sampleuser3' }]
  
  ];

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
    const object = myArray[i][j];
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array destructuring on the `userSelected` argument. The would give you the first element of an `myArray`'s item:

```
    const forEachUser = await Promise.all(myArray.map(async ([userSelected]) => 
    {
        engagements.push(buildEmailPayload(bridgeInfo, userSelected, incident));
        const callPayload = buildCallPayload(bridgeInfo, userSelected, incident);

    })
```

If you need to get `username`, add object destructuring:

```
    const forEachUser = await Promise.all(myArray.map(async ([{username}]) => 
    {
        engagements.push(buildEmailPayload(bridgeInfo, username, incident));
        const callPayload = buildCallPayload(bridgeInfo, username, incident);

    })
```